# WPF: Set Value on Visibility Trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I was wondering why this XAML code is not working:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxFilterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeCheckboxStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Obviously I am aiming to deselect a checkbox when its visibility is set to "Collapsed".

My current solution is a function that sets both properties at the same time in codebehind, but this was my first approach. I'd really appreciate a tip, on why this is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the style. What about the control using the style? Could you show us that?

Comment: In case you have assigned a local value to the CheckBox's IsChecked property (i.e. directly set it to a boolean value or a Binding), this has higher precedence than the value from the Style Setter. Hence the Setter would be ignored.

Comment: I think Clemens is likely correct since this works if I try some code without setting the value.

Comment: I agree with @Clemens, see [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) on MSDocs.

Comment: Thanks everybody.